# Unordered collection for mutable objects in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, collections

The task I have at hand is to parse a large text (several 100K rows) file and accumulate some statistics based which will be then visualized in plots. Each row contains results of some prior analysis.

I wrote a custom class to define the objects that are to be accumulated. The class contains 2 string fields, 3 sets and 2 integer counters. As such there is an `__init__(self, name)` which initializes a new object with name and empty fields, and a method called `addRow()` which adds information into the object. The sets accumulate data to be associated with this object and the counters keep track of a couple of conditions.

My original idea was to iterate over the rows of the file and call a method like `parseRow()` in `main`

```
reader = csv.reader(f)
acc = {} # or set()
for row in reader: 
  parseRow(row,acc)
```

which would look something like:

```
parseRow(row, acc):
  if row[id] is not in acc: # row[id] is the column where the object names/ids are 
    a = MyObj(row[id])
  else:
    a = acc.get(row[id]) # or equivalent
  a.addRow(...)
```

The issue here is that the accumulating collection `acc` cannot be a `set` since sets are apparently not indexable in Python. **Edit:** for clarification, by *indexable* I didn't mean getting the nth element but rather being able to **retrieve a specific element**.

One workaround would be to have a `dict` that has `{obj_name : obj}` mapping but it feels like an ugly solution. Considering the elegance of the language otherwise, I guess there is a better solution to this. It's surely not a particularly rare situation...

Any suggestions?

Comment: How can you have something that's unordered and indexable? What does it mean to get the first thing from an unordered collection?

Comment: @jonrsharpe my bad, by indexable I meant something where you can do a get operation a la `d["myitem"]` or like `s.get("myitem")`

Comment: It is not clear why an dict "feels" like an "ugly" solution. Do you want to index something (mutable object) with a value (immutable object). That is a dict. The Python dict object has the very nice setdefault method, which might compress your parseRow function to an oneliner. However, the question is not clear - what is row, id, acc? How is acc populated?

Comment: @oekopez tried to clarify the programming bits further. As for why it feels like a hack, well it's because I am storing the same thing twice by using a dict `{id : myobj}` if `myobj` already has the field stored `id`.

Comment: That is why you should state "I want to avoid memory overhead" and not write "ugly", which is in the eye of the beholder.  To avoid memory overhead in a limited system, I would suggest moving the id from the class to the index. If you do not suffer from memory limitations, I would not worry, but write readable code. Please avoid "feel" and "ugly" in your question but rather state the problem. You can do really nice things with dicts. Any custom made container is likely to be overenegineering of a non existant problem, and certainly slower than the built in dict lookup.

Comment: @oekopez ok, i think i get the picture.. thanks anyways

Answer (score 0):

You could also try an [ordered-set](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ordered-set). Which is a set AND ordered.